# When I try to use a variable for my WHERE in SQL PHP it doesn't work

Tags: php, sql, variables, sql-update, where-clause

This is a segment of my code where I'm trying to edit a record using WHERE. When I enter the id number manually it edits the record and says record updated successfully. When I use a variable taken from the previous page the record says record updated successfully but doesn't change my record.

This works where I manually put in the ID to edit

```
// Create connection
        $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
        // Check connection
        if ($conn->connect_error) {
            die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
        }

            $student_ID = $_GET{'student_ID'};

            $sql =  "UPDATE student_info_2020 SET student_first_name = '$student_first_name', student_last_name = '$student_last_name', student_username = '$student_username',student_password = '$student_password',
            student_program = '$student_program', student_portfolio = '$student_portfolio', student_linkedin = '$student_linkedin', student_secondary = '$student_secondary', student_hometown = '$student_hometown',
            student_career_goals = '$student_career_goals', student_hobbies = '$student_hobbies', student_state = '$student_state' WHERE student_ID = 2";


        if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
            echo "Record updated successfully";
        } else {
            echo "Error updating record: " . $conn->error;
        }

    $conn->close();
```

When I try to use a variable for my WHERE clause it doesn't work. I've echoed out the $student_ID and it came up with a correct number which was two but didn't edit record 2. It also reports the record was updated successfully but it didn't so I'm fairly confused.

```
// Create connection
        $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
        // Check connection
        if ($conn->connect_error) {
            die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
        }

            $student_ID = $_GET{'student_ID'};

            $sql =  "UPDATE student_info_2020 SET student_first_name = '$student_first_name', student_last_name = '$student_last_name', student_username = '$student_username',student_password = '$student_password',
            student_program = '$student_program', student_portfolio = '$student_portfolio', student_linkedin = '$student_linkedin', student_secondary = '$student_secondary', student_hometown = '$student_hometown',
            student_career_goals = '$student_career_goals', student_hobbies = '$student_hobbies', student_state = '$student_state' WHERE student_ID = '$student_ID'";


        if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
            echo "Record updated successfully";
        } else {
            echo "Error updating record: " . $conn->error;
        }

    $conn->close();
```

Comment: Another example from the same project     $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT student_password FROM student_info_2020 WHERE student_username = '$inName'");  doesnt work but this does $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT student_password FROM student_info_2020 WHERE student_username = moonman");

Answer (score 0):

Use `[` and `]` for getting value from `$_GET` array:

```
$student_ID = $_GET['student_ID'];
```

Try to use sprintf

```
$sql =  sprintf("UPDATE student_info_2020 SET student_first_name = '$student_first_name', student_last_name = '$student_last_name', student_username = '$student_username',student_password = '$student_password',
        student_program = '$student_program', student_portfolio = '$student_portfolio', student_linkedin = '$student_linkedin', student_secondary = '$student_secondary', student_hometown = '$student_hometown',
        student_career_goals = '$student_career_goals', student_hobbies = '$student_hobbies', student_state = '$student_state' WHERE student_ID = %d",(int)$student_ID);
```

Comment: that didn't work either. I don't understand why it works when I manually put a number in this is so frustrating lol.